# How do I delete a file with PHP on my server?

Tags: php, html, download, delete-file

I have this in a html file:

```
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) 
{
   echo "{$filename}<a href='download.php?file=$filename'>Download</a><br>" . "\n";
}
```

So it will print out a download link for all .txt files. But now I also want for each link a delete button. So there are able to delete a textfile of the server.

I read somewhere that you have to be carefull with letting people deleting files of your server, is this true?

If you need more info, please say so.

Comment: You can use the `unlink()` function to delete files.

Comment: "be carefull" means, not to do things like `?file=$filename` ... this way I may delete files I choose, NOT YOU. (Assuming this is unsanitized and not whitelisted $_GET['filename'].)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the permissions just use **`unlink('yourfilename.extension');`**

Example

```
<?php
$fh = fopen('test.html', 'a');
fwrite($fh, '<h1>Hello world!</h1>');
fclose($fh);

unlink('test.html');
?>
```

[**Source**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)